# asymptotic behaviour of the solution of the o.d.e of the form: $\dot{\theta}(t) = \left(\frac{A}{\theta_i(t)} - B\right)\theta(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour of the solution of the o.d.e of the form:
$$\dot{\theta}(t) = \left(\frac{A}{\theta_i(t)} - B\right)\theta(t)$$
where $A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices and $\theta_i(.)$ is the $i$-th component of $\theta(.)$.

Comment: It is the same $i$ for every equation in the system?

Comment: @LutzL: yes. It is some fixed $i$.